# bookdown::render_book vs. rmarkdown::render_site to build all outputs

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I've got a Bookdown book for which I'd like to build a GitBook site as well as PDF and EPUB downloads. I will use Travis to build all 3 outputs, and the PDF and EPUB will be available for download from the GitBook site.

The `bookdown-demo` calls `bookdown::render_book` once for each output in [_build.sh](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo/blob/master/_build.sh).

However, according to the logs in RStudio, the `Build Book` button, when building `All Formats`, uses `rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = 'UTF-8')` to build all outputs in a single command.

I'd like to ensure what happens on my CI server is exactly what happens in my IDE, so it seems like I should have Travis call `rmarkdown::render_site` rather than several invocations of `bookdown::render_book` as is done by the `bookdown-demo`. However, Yihui is the expert, and he has chosen to use the latter approach.

So, my question: what is the best script to invoke on a continuous integration server like Travis when multiple outputs will be built?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **bookdown** projects, they usually don't make a difference, because `rmarkdown::render_site()` [eventually calls](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/7b94fc258b7b185e9187e853bc38070eb22d1d1c/R/site.R#L30-L38) `bookdown::render_book()` to render your book. Feel free to use either way.

The only exception is when your `index.Rmd` *does not* contain the field `site: bookdown::bookdown_site`. In that case, `rmarkdown::render_site()` won't work, because it doesn't know this is supposed to be a **bookdown** project.

BTW, to render all output formats with `bookdown::render_book()`, you can use the argument `output_format = 'all'`.

Comment: my issue was that my file was named `.rmd` instead of `.Rmd`